# Using ZeroMQ/ZMQ in react js for subscribing data

Tags: reactjs, zeromq

I want to use `ZeroMQ`/`ZMQ` in `react-js` app to subscribe connection and monitor data response from python app .have you ever anyone to use this app in `React` and have an example when I use

```
var zmq = require('../');var sock = zmq.socket('sub');

error TypeError: zmq.zmqVersion is not a function
```

and failed project anyone can help me with this problem when I run example without `React` app its work correctly, but when I import in the project it's going to error.

Comment: Where are you importing zmq from ?

Comment: from source of zeromq js project `http://zeromq.github.io/zeromq.js/` and another try I'm import from package of nom `var zmq = require('zeromq')`

Comment: @VikasYadav from Mohammad-reza1987: "from source of zeromq js project http://zeromq.github.io/zeromq.js/ and another try I'm import from package of nom var zmq = require('zeromq')"